# Error using iCacls

Tags: icacls

I saved an ACL using icacls using this command

```
icacls File.zip /save aclsFile
```

That worked fine, but whenever I try to restore the file I get an error message:

```
icacls * /restore aclsFile
Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is UAC enabled on your system? You need to run your command prompt as administrator in order for icacls restore to work.

Also - I'm pretty sure the format of your restore command is incorrect. A * will cause icacls to error out because it will look for *\File.zip - what you probably want is:

```
icacls . /restore aclsFile
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about running command prompt as an Administrator.